# Font degradation issue

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm beginning to learn the basics of HTML and CSS and am currently working through the FreeCodeCamp program. Currently, I cannot create an account to access the forums there so I'm going to attempt to solve it here. Within the problem, it's asking the user to add a second font and comment out the Google font import at the top. Everything is correct and accepted as so yet it's saying the H2 element must use the "Lobster" font. The problem is that the current font is already set the "Lobster".

I've tried adding a separate font-family beneath the Lobster font, but this removes the functionality of the degradation feature. This did not work. I also attempted to rearrange the formatting of the code but doing so breaks it even more. Here are the directions:

> Your h2 element should use the font Lobster.
>
> Your h2 element should degrade to the font monospace when Lobster is
>   not available.
>
> Comment out your call to Google for the Lobster font by putting
>
> Be sure to close your comment by adding -->.

```
<!--<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->
<style>
  .red-text {
    color: red;
  }

  h2 {
    font-family: Lobster, monospace;
  }

  p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: monospace;
  }
</style>

<h2 class="red-text">CatPhotoApp</h2>
<main>
  <p class="red-text">Click here to view more <a href="#">cat photos</a>.</p>

  <a href="#"><img src="image-removed" alt="A cute orange cat lying on its back."></a>

  <div>
    <p>Things cats love:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>cat nip</li>
      <li>laser pointers</li>
      <li>lasagna</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Top 3 things cats hate:</p>
    <ol>
      <li>flea treatment</li>
      <li>thunder</li>
      <li>other cats</li>
    </ol>
  </div>

  <form action="/submit-cat-photo">
    <label><input type="radio" name="indoor-outdoor" checked> Indoor</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="indoor-outdoor"> Outdoor</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="personality" checked> Loving</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="personality"> Lazy</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="personality">                                                    Energetic</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="cat photo URL" required>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </main>
```

I expect everything to be correct as is, and for this to be an error on the program's end. Unlikely.. but I'm confident I followed the directions accurately.

Comment: Why is the `<link` commented?

Comment: It asks for the user to comment out the imported Google Font

Answer (score 0):

In this challenge,you just need to write.

```
h2 {
    font-family: Lobster,monospace;
  }
```

and comment the google font link .

This challenge just told us how browser is work(take monospace font) when they did not get primary font(Lobster).

Comment: I've done so already, yet the first requirement "Your h2 element should use the font Lobster" is not fulfilled.

Comment: Is Lobster font is install in your computer?

Comment: From what I'm able to tell.. no. Running xubuntu though so not sure if it could be hidden somewhere other than the font manager.

Answer (score -1):

The error can be resolved by using this exact line ;

h2 { font-family: Lobster,monospace; }

the excercise will only work when there is **no space** from ***Lobster to the semi-colon after monospace***.
.
.
.
.
.

HERE is the code you can copy paste it ;

```
h2 {
    font-family: Lobster,monospace;
  }
```